# UIGestureRecognizer giving me error on ipod but not in iphone simulator?

Tags: objective-c, ios, unrecognized-selector, uipangesturerecognizer

In my program, I have declared a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and it works very well in the iPhone simulator. However, when I run it on my iPod (iOS 3.1) it gives me the error `[UIPanGestureRecognizer locationInView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11cd80.` Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIPanGestureRecognizer` is available in iOS 3.2 and later. Please check the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)